# Load particular stylesheet in rails per variable

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass

I wish to have a subdirectory  (call it `custom`) within my `assets/stylesheets` that contains several different custom stylesheets. My app is for management of different events and each event has a different instance of the app running. Those custom stylesheets would contain instance-specific css (i.e. a different background color to match the event's logo). In the app there is an `EventsConfiguration` model and I would like to be able to choose one of the stylesheets in `assets/stylesheets/custom` to save as a variable in that model. I then would not want any of the other custom css files to be used.

The custom css file should be loaded after all of the other css files (compiled into application.scss) so that it can override.

Right now `application.scss` has `*= require_tree .` in it. It would be nice to leave that so that sprockets automatically includes all css files but I want it to exclude the `custom` subdirectory. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by re-organizing the assets directory. One suggestion is to:

1. Move common stylesheets under `assets/stylesheets/common`
2. `application.scss` contains the following as well as any other stylesheets that are not custom:

   `*= require_tree ./common`
3. Create event specific stylesheets (`custom_event.scss`):

   `*= require_tree ./common`

   `*= require_tree ./custom_event`

You can then require the correct stylesheet in your view based on the configuration parameter.  Keeping stylesheets modular will very much help in the long run.

Comment: What do you mean by "You can then require the correct stylesheet in your view based on the configuration parameter."?

Comment: I mean, depending on the `EventsConfiguration` parameter, in the view, you can require the correct stylesheet. Eg: `EventsConfiguration.where(:name => "custom_event")`...

Comment: What I ended up doing was `<%= stylesheet_link_tag "#EventConfiguration.short_name.downcase.tr(" ", "_")}" %>` where `short_name` is the name of the event.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to exclude the `custom` directory is that moves the `custom` directory to your `lib/assets/stylesheets`, then `application.scss` will not include it.